# xcode 4 interface builder name objects

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

With interface builder for xcode 3 i could rename an object by clicking on its name in the outline view. Is there a way to rename objects in interface builder for xcode 4? Because an outline like this:

```
View
    View
    View
    View
         View
         View
    View
```

could be a little more informative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to rename the objects. First, select an object and open the identity inspector. In the Identity section there is a Label text field. Enter the name in the text field.

Second, you can change the object list, which runs along the left side of the editor, from the icon view to the hierarchical view. The hierarchical view shows the document outline, which looks similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

Select an object from the object list and press the Return key to rename the object. How you change to the hierarchical view depends on the Xcode 4 version you're using. Newer versions have a button in the lower left corner of the canvas that toggles the icon and hierarchical views. Older versions have a small button at the bottom of the object list.

Comment: ah, thank you. one thing though, when i select an object and press the return key all i get is a system beep.

Comment: I can't reproduce your system beep, but there is an alternative to pressing the Return key. After selecting an object from the object list (like the View object in the screenshot I posted), clicking the mouse will also allow you to rename the object.